# Logout API for beats music service

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm able to login into Beats service on behalf of the resource owner. Is there any API to logout from Beats service? I don't see any documentation to sign out.

Answer (score 0):

I think "log out" just means "forget the auth token you were given".

No need for an API call to forget something (:

Are you worried about someone stealing that auth token, and you want to somehow forcibly invalidate it?
The tokens expire fairly quickly, from what I see on the docs.